# Can't see .js.map files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-filerev to create minimized javascript files.

on my website each js file signed with the map file at the end,

I can access directly to the map file and it downloaded successfully.

The name of the map file is the same name of the .js file but with the extension .js.map

Although, when i'm using chrome developer tools i can only see the js file and not the map file.

I understood that in previous chrome developer tools there was option that needed to be checked "show map files" but in the new one there isn't.

If you have any idea why can i see the map file, i will be thankful.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the path to the `sourceMappingURL` to see if that is what Chrome needs?

Comment: @Seamus yes and nothing happens after i click "Add"

Comment: @Seamus is it possible that it's not working with https maybe ?

Comment: I have not had any trouble with https. But you could certainly try switching.